# Can't connect to school internet

Tags: wireless, networking, internet

I recently got a new ubuntu laptop for school. The only problem is that I cannot connect to my school's network. To connect I have to select the network in my network list, then open a web browser and sign in. I can connect to the sign in page, and enter my credentials, but I can't browse the internet on other websites. The school internet works fine, I can connect on my phone, just not my computer.

This is not a problem with my computer, as I can connect fine at home.

If anyone has a way to fix this, please respond as soon as possible, as I take online courses, and without a working web browser I cannot attend class.

Comment: You take online courses, so your issue is that you can't connect TO your school FROM your home. Is that what you mean? Sorry, but it seems a little unclear for me what you're asking.

Comment: Does the school use a proxy server you have to set up first?

Comment: You should contact your school for assistance.

Comment: It sounds like you will have to manually enter the DNS server IP addresses in your Network Connections. Click on the WiFi icon. Select "Edit Connections..." Choose your School's WiFi SSID and select edit. Then enter the DNS server IP addresses you get from the school's tech support.

Comment: are you using firefox as browser, by any chance? type in the address bar "about: config", press "I'll be careful" button, and then search for ipv, and make sure the line "network.dns.disableIPv6" has value set to "false". I've had a similar issue on Fedora installation. I was connecting to home network, could go to google , but not other websites, until I changed that value.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problems on my university In public networks you sometimes need certificates for that Network (You've been asked for a CA on connection and ignored it).
This certificates should be provided by your school.